# Osgi Declarative service conditional binding

Tags: osgi, declarative-services

I have this scenario, I have three declarative services that provide the same interface (say a reader interface and I have readerimpl1-database- readerimpl2-flat file- readerimpl3-memory). I want to have a consumer that binds only to the database implementation. In the component definition we give it a name so I am pretty sure that the name is in the registry so if I were to add an activate method I can lookup from the component context using the name.

I want to try to it via the bind/unbind though using the service name as the parameter. I am pretty sure that the "target" parameter in the component reference element can be used to do this but I have not found how to use it.

Has anyone else done this?

This would be similar to using
@Reference(mapped-name="foo")

Comment: This is a really interesting question. It makes me think of the related question of if you *prefer* the database impl but will accept another. In that scenario, you could implement via @Reference(cardinality=ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE,policy=ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC) and then sift through the list in your add/remove methods.

Answer (score 15):

Target is simply an OSGi [filter](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/Filter.html). You can use it to filter by any service property. So, if your services have property named `backend` with values `file` or `database`, you can bind with the following target:

```
<scr:reference ... target="(backend=database)"/>
```

And the service with database backend itself will register as:

```
<scr:component ...>
    ...
    <property name="backend" type="String" value="database"/>
</scr:component>
```